# How to show file sizes In Midnight Commander in the most compact form? ("smart file sizes" in Total Commander)

Tags: midnight-commander

MC shows file sizes in kilobytes and bytes by default, but it is hard to read, and it would be easier to see them in the "closest" unit available. That is:

```
1234567  -> 1M  
123456   -> 123K
12345678 -> 12M
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Option 1: Using the interface

Change it in one of the panels by

1. Pressing <kbd>F9</kbd>
2. Choose `Left` (or `Right`)
3. Select `Listing format...`
4. Check `User defined:` and set the size string to `size:4` and select `OK`. It should look like this:

   ```
     ┌────────────── Listing format ──────────────┐
     │ ( ) Full file list                         │
     │ ( ) Brief file list: 2        [^] columns  │
     │ ( ) Long file list                         │
     │ (*) User defined:                          │
     │ half type name | size:4 | perm         [^] │
     ├────────────────────────────────────────────┤
     │ [ ] User mini status                       │
     │ half type name | size | perm           [^] │
     ├────────────────────────────────────────────┤
     │            [< OK >] [ Cancel ]             │
     └────────────────────────────────────────────┘
   ```
5. To make it permanent, <kbd>F9</kbd> > `Options` > `Save setup`.

#### Option 2: Editing the configuration file

Edit the file `~/.config/mc/panels.ini`. There should be two `user_format=` entries, one under `[New Left Panel]` and other under `[New Right Panel]`. Change the entry of the desired panel to

```
user_format=half type name | size:4 | perm
```

#### The documentation

The relevant quote of the [documentation](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/mc-data/mc.1.en.html), under *Listing Format...*:

> **To  force one field to a fixed size (a size specifier), you just add `:` followed by the number of characters you want the field to have.**  If the number is followed by the symbol `+`, then the size specifies the minimal field size - if the program finds out that there is more space on the screen, it will  then  expand that field.

Therefore, `bsize:4` is also possible. It is equal to `size:4`, except that for directories it just shows SUB-DIR or UP--DIR.